# Pass datetime to stored procedure

Tags: c#, datetime, sql-server-2012

Using sql server 2012. I'm having a hard time passing a date parameter to the stored procedure.
The column's datatype in the table is `datetime`.

```
alter procedure savedate()
(
  @StartDate datetime
)
```

The text from the source textbox is 2014-09-18.

The below code will give an error - string not recognized as valid datetime

```
SqlParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
SqlParams[0].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text.Trim());//error here
```

And this will say - Failed to convert parameter value from string to datetime

```
SqlParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
SqlParams[0].Value = txtStartDate.Text.Trim();
SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "savedate",
                         SqlParams); //error here
```

I'm reading about culture variants, but dont know how to fix this.

Comment: This has nothing to do at all with SQL totally. It is "I have no idea how to parse a string into a DateTime". - which you should do explicitly. I.e. instead of txtStartDate.Text.Trim() you should parse it there and turn the resulting DateTime into SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to get your string converted to a datetime then pass the datetime

```
string test = "2014-09-18";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
SqlParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
SqlParams[0].Value = dt;
```

If your input comes from a user typed value, then it is probably better to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify the input without getting an exception.

```
if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(test, "yyyy-MM-dd", 
             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Type a date in the format yyyy-MM-dd");
    return;
}
```