# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string from a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I know this problem has been answered before but I don't see a solution I can apply to this.

Error on Line 37 from the code behind.

```
Line 35:         For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
Line 36:             'If IsRowModified(r) Then     GridView1.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, False)
Line 37:             GridView1.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, False)
Line 38:         Next
```

My code in the gridview.

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PROMISEDELDATE" SortExpression="PROMISEDELDATE" ItemStyle-Width="100">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:label ID="PromiseDelDateTextBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Bind("PROMISEDELDATE") %>' Width="50px"></asp:label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="25px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm calling a stored procedures with 6 parameters.

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="CUST_ORDER_ID" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ORDER_LINE_SUMMARY" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="TRIP_ORDER" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="PROMISEDELDATE" Type="datetime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="JOB_DEL_NOTES" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ORDER_DEL_NOTES" Type="String" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Executing this same data into the stored procedure works fine. I've checked SQL Server Profiler and this is what is getting passed to stored procedure:

```
exec CM_SP_UPDATE_TRIP N'1,2,3', N'1', '2016-06-23 00:00:00', N'MIKE TEST', N'MIKE TEST', N'37389-1'
```

Yet when running from my asp.net page I get the error with the same result from SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886290/pass-datetime-to-stored-procedure

Comment: Then the error is likely in your procedure. Most likely the where predicate is trying to compare some text column (that should be a date) and there is a value that cannot be cast to a date. Maybe you can make the contents of your procedure simply be "select 1" or something to eliminate the body of the procedure. You first are going to have to identify where the error is occurring. It is somewhere in those 6 procedures. Once you know where it is it will likely be somewhat trivial to fix.

Comment: Why do you include `PROMISEDELDATE` in update parameters? It is bind to a `asp:Label` that is `span` and cannot be changed. I'm not sure that `Bind` works with `asp:Label` in two-way.

Comment: I include PROMISEDELDATE beucase it is needed inside the proc and if I don't bind it, the parameter is null when it gets to sql server.  Again when I execute the procedure in SSMS it updates the tables and SQL profiler confirms a return of 0.

Comment: The other problem I have any maybe its related.  I hard coded a date into the stored proc to eliminate the date error.  When I execute from SSMS it works.  When I call it from the asp page it doesn't update and there are no errors and with Profiler on I can see that the parameters passed the data into the stored procedure. I'm very lost on this.